# Does gcc include some header files automatically?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have the following code:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it using the following command:

```
gcc -o myprogram myfile.c
```

And it compiled without any error even though I did not `#include <stdio.h>`. So did gcc include this header file automatically?

**My gcc version is 4.3.3**

Comment: It might not have given an error: but it did give a warning (if you looked). It made assumptions about the function prototype (in the missing header), and linked the library automatically.

Answer (score 3):

In ANSI C, you can call functions you didn't declare. Such functions are implicitly declared the first time you call them. They are assumed to return `int` and take arguments according to the *default argument promotions.* Since you didn't include `<stdio.h>`, the compiler uses this rule and implicitly declares `printf`. Note that this is undefined behaviour as functions that take variable argument lists like `printf` must be declared explicitly. gcc usually warns you if it uses the implicit declaration rule since it's usually not intentionally used.

Comment: gcc did not give me any warning when I used the following command: `gcc -o myprogram myfile.c`. Also the program worked fine and printed `"Hello"`.

Comment: Doubtful about "this is undefined behaviour as functions that take variable argument lists like printf must be declared explicitly"  Any citation available?

Comment: @Tom compile with `-Wall`

Comment: @chux C11 6.5.2.2/6   (C89 and C99 had similar text). Standard library functions are considered to be defined with a prototype.

Comment: Since C99 missing declarations have to generate a warning.

Comment: @Tom: Use C99 mode, gcc that old defaults to C90 at best. And get a more recent version.

Comment: Old gcc defaults to `-std=gnu89` (i.e. C89/C90 with GNU extensions).

Comment: @melpomene: IIRC, it defaults to `gnu90`.

Comment: @Olaf Which is the same thing. Newer gcc defaults to `gnu11`.

Comment: @FUZxxl: To be precise gcc 5 and newer:-)

Comment: @M.M Thanks for the cite.  As I read it, it does not support "UB as  functions that take variable argument lists like printf must be declared explicitly".  It also needs incompatibility.  I read that spec as functions like `printf()`  (those with a `...`) and _the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is undefined._ Yet if the arguments happed to be compatible, it is not UB.  Thus with OP's lack of `stdio.h`, the format happened to be compatible and so things worked.  Obviously not portable code.

Comment: @chux ISO 9899 §3.3.2.2 ¶6 is quite clear in this regard: *If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
does not include a prototype, the integral promotions are performed on
each argument and arguments that have type float are promoted to
double. [...] If the function is defined with
a type that includes a prototype, and the types of the arguments after
promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters, or if
the prototype ends with an ellipsis ( ", ..." ), the behavior is
undefined.*

Answer (score 1):

No, gcc did not include any header files you didn't request.  `#include` statements are C preprocessor macros (like `#define` or `#if`) that are actually evaluated before the actual C compilation.  You can see what your code looks like after all macros are resolved by calling `gcc -E myfile.c`.  As you will see, `printf` will still not be declared.

If you compile with `-Wall`, you should get a warning that `printf` is undeclared.  However gcc "guesses" how `printf` is used (probably from its arguments, but it could also simply know the routine internally).  Since it finds a matching symbol name while linking, you don't get an error and your program runs just fine.

BTW, gcc 5.3.0 shows the following warning:

```
myfile.c: In function 'main':
myfile.c:3:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'printf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     printf("Hello\n");
     ^
myfile.c:3:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'
myfile.c:3:5: note: include '<stdio.h>' or provide a declaration of 'printf'
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent gcc from doing these "guesses"?

Comment: Or try compile with -Werror-implicit-function-declaration